# Advantage of inputs/targets to be normally distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normality-assumption

Why is it advantageous for inputs/targets to most ML algorithms like neural nets to be normally distributed? I am not talking about mean normalization, but in some cases of skewed data, people perform log transform to make it more normal. Example: https://medium.com/ml-byte/rare-feature-engineering-techniques-for-machine-learning-competitions-de36c7bb418f here the last tip says to convert targets by log(1+target) to do so. Why? Why does it become easier to fit or improve accuracy?

P.S I know from studying linear models that those models model how variances in the input affect the variance in the output. So the mean and variances that we normalize by are just shift and scaling factors that act on the true relationship between the variables. But i'm not sure of log transforms and such and why it easier here.

Comment: Your reference doesn't include the word "normal" anywhere, indicating you are reading more into it than is there.  An alternative reading is that transformations are applied for other reasons, many of which can be discovered by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transformation+-normal*).

Comment: It says : "Just, transforming the target variable wit h log(1+target) gives more near-to gaussian distribution." But it was a general question as well.

Comment: Thank you for that specific quotation--I should have remembered that many people use "Gaussian" as a synonym.  (+1)

Comment: Any insights @whuber? Would like your input.

Comment: I have written about this issue in several places, including  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3530/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4833/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24236/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10979/919, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323410 (at the end).

Comment: Thanks! I will start reading into them.